# Combine multiple fields with awk

Tags: shell, awk

I want to get `abc/123/efg` from `abc/123/efg/456`

I try to get the first `NF - 1` fields and concatenate them with `/`.

So I do:

```
echo abc/123/efg/456 | awk -F "/" 'BEGIN {OFS="/"} {for(i=1;i<=NF-1;i++) {var = var+$i} END {print var}'
```

However, it did not work as I expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any way to do this more elegantly?

Comment: Use `var"/"$i}}` at the end, i.e missing `}` and removing `+`.

Comment: Also change the loop to `for(i=1;i<NF;i++)`. No need to `-1`

Comment: `dirname 'abc/123/efg/456'`?

Comment: `cut -d/ -f4 --complement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach: Remove the last field. Yes, it is that easy. The code:

```bash
echo "abc/123/efg/456" | awk -F/ -vOFS=/ '{NF--; print}'
```

Notes

- The flag `-F/` specifies the input field separator
- The flag `-vOFS=/` specifies the output field separator
- The `NF--` statement decreases the number of fields by one
- The `print` statement prints the whole record (line) after the removal of the last field

Comment: decrementing `NF` is undefined behavior per POSIX so what that does will vary depending on the version of awk you're running. It'd also produce an error for a blank input line.

Comment: Without a space between `-v` and the variable name the script is non-portable, just change `-vOFS=/` to `-v OFS=/` and then that part will work in all awks.

Answer (score 3):

To fix your code:

```
echo "abc/123/efg/456" | awk -F "/" 'BEGIN {OFS="/"} {
  for(i=1;i<NF;i++) var = (var ? var OFS : "") $i
}
END {print var}'
```

As an alternative, you might for example remove starting from the last occurrence of `/` until the end of the string.

```
echo "abc/123/efg/456" | awk '{sub("/[^/]*$", "")}1'
```

Output

```
abc/123/efg
```

Comment: `sub` is probably the simplest of all the solutions

Comment: That `sub()` is definitely the best way to do this as it's portable to all awks and wouldn't fail given an empty input line.

Comment: @EdMorton : and i just gave 4 different solutions that are all fully portable, handles extra blank lines, and none of them calls any function at all

Answer (score 2):

One idea would be to decrement `NF`, eg:

```
$ echo 'abc/123/efg/456' | awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="/"} NF--'
abc/123/efg
```

Whether or not this is the 'best' solution is going to depend on the rest of  your coding requirements, ie:

- if you're doing additional work within `awk` then this could be combined with other `awk` scripting
- if the only purpose of `awk` is to strip off the last field then this may be overkill and a better (?) solution may be to perform the operation in `bash` (eg, parameter substitution, `dirname`, etc)

Comment: The `NF--` is a nice touch.

Comment: decrementing `NF` is undefined behavior per POSIX so what that does will vary depending on the version of awk you're running. It'd also produce an error for a blank input line.

Answer (score 0):

simplest approach (if you're concerned with extra blank lines)

```
echo 'abc/123/efg/456\n\n' |
```

> ```
>  nawk 'NF=(-_<NF) * 3' FS='[/]' OFS='/'    
>  mawk 'NF * (NF = 3)' FS='[/]' OFS='/'
> ```

```
abc/123/efg
```

if you're concerned about decrementing NF all the way to negative zone :

> ```
> mawk2 'NF -= !!NF' FS='[/]' OFS='/'
> ```

or just have `FS + OFS` scrub it for u, risk free :

> ```
>  gawk NF=NF FS='[/][^/]*$' OFS=
> ```

if those represent nested folders/directories of any kind, then use this trick to get a 2D tree view :

> ```
>  nawk 'NF-=!!NF' FS='[/]' OFS='\f\b/'
> ```

```
abc
  /123
     /efg
```